# Circle Equation isn't plotting --

Tags: plotting

I have a circle square root equation but Mathematica is not recognizing it.[image]

I need it in a piecewise function and while the other parts graph out correctly, this one does plot at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Sqrt[]`...

Comment: Something to note is that all built-in functions in Mathematica begin with a capital letter, and function calls require square brackets. Also, if you see a term highlighted in bright blue, it means that Mathematica doesn't know what that thing is. Sometimes that's fine because you're creating your own variable and will store something in it later, but if it's a built-in function it probably means it is not spelled correctly or doesn't have capital letters in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[Sqrt[4.1915^2 - (x - 4.1915)^2] + 1.25, 
{x, 0, 9},
 AspectRatio -> 5/9]
```

[image]

Or try:

```
Plot[{Sqrt[4.1915^2 - (x - 4.1915)^2] + 1.25, 
     -Sqrt[4.1915^2 - (x - 4.1915)^2] + 1.25},
  {x, 0, 9},
 PlotStyle -> Red,
 AspectRatio -> 10/9]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!